# ListView doesn’t show up (Xamarin)

Tags: android, listview, xamarin

[Screenprint.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fj5Nj.png) I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zZHLHrkvUt0&list=PLCuRg51-gw5VqYchUekCqxUS9hEZkDf6l&index=2) exercise "Xamarin Android Tutorial 2 Creating a ListView". Here's my code:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ListViewTutorial
{
    [Activity(Label = "ListViewTutorial", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        int count = 1;
        private List<string> mItems; // 1 Create a list
        private ListView mListView; // 3 Get the list view


        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            mListView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.myListView); // 4 Get the reference to the ListView

            mItems = new List<String>(); // 2 Instantiate the list and populate it
            mItems.Add("Bob");
            mItems.Add("Tom");
            mItems.Add("Jim");

            ArrayAdapter<string> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, mItems); // 5 Instantiate the adapter

            mListView.Adapter = adapter; // 6
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Main.axml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/myListView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that my ListView doesn't show anything. Where am i going wrong? I believe my code is identical to the code on the video.

Comment: I have tested your code and it works correctly. Try a clean and rebuild.

Comment: Thank you. It didn't help. Here is the link to the screenprint. The listview doesn't show up even in the design mode. http://i.stack.imgur.com/fj5Nj.png

Comment: Did you actually run it in the emulator or on a real device?

Comment: I did in the emulator. There is no difference.